# simple_form f.hidden_field works, why not f.input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

```
= simple_form_for @foo do |f|

  # this works
  = f.hidden_field :asdf, :value => @some.thing

  # this works
  = f.input :asdf, :as => "hidden", :input_html => { :value => @some.thing }

  # Why doesn't this work, exactly?
  = f.input :title, :as => "hidden", :value => @some.thing
```

When I look at my log I see that value is coming through as an empty string in the latter input, but it's not clear to me why this is happening.

Comment: Show the HTML the form renders.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`f.hidden_field` is a [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field) while `f.input` belongs to [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage).

The syntax is similar but has some differences.